# MySql: WHERE NOT EXISTS (skip duplicates) with group by

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

I have this challenge, I'm into a kind of solution, but I dont'understand why is it wrong.

Write a query to print the hacker_id, name, and the total number of challenges created by each student. Sort your results by the total number of challenges in descending order. If more than one student created the same number of challenges, then sort the result by hacker_id. If more than one student created the same number of challenges and the count is less than the maximum number of challenges created, then exclude those students from the result.

Hackers: The hacker_id is the id of the hacker, and name is the name of the hacker.
Challenges: The challenge_id is the id of the challenge, and hacker_id is the id of the student who created the challenge.

My solution:

```
select h.hacker_id, h.name, count(c.challenge_id) as total from challenges c

join hackers h
on h.hacker_id= c.hacker_id


where not exists
      (select h1.hacker_id, h1.name, count(C1.challenge_id) as total1 from challenges C1
      join hackers h1 on h1.hacker_id= c1.hacker_id
      group by h1.hacker_id, h1.name
      having total1 < max(count(c.challenge_id)  and  total1 = count(c.challenge_id)
      order by total1 desc)
       

group by h.hacker_id, h.name
order by total desc
```

I get this error:
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order by total1 desc)

group by h.hacker_id, h.name
order by total desc' at line 16

Comment: The internal order by is meaningless, so just remove it.

Comment: ...as is anything other than 'SELECT 1' on an exists query

Comment: And I suspect you already know that max(count is never going to work. Maybe see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and start over

Comment: Make sure the numbers of '(' and ')' are the same in your query. (Currently they are not equal).

Comment: I changed following your advice, but now i get a new error. ERROR 1248 (42000) at line 2: Every derived table must have its own alias

Answer (score 0):

```
select h.hacker_id, h.name, count(c.challenge_id) as total from challenges c

join hackers h
on h.hacker_id= c.hacker_id


where not exists
(select t.total1
 
 from (select  count(C1.challenge_id) as total1 
      from challenges C1
join hackers h1 on h1.hacker_id = c1.hacker_id
group by h1.hacker_id) t
having t.total1 < big = (select max(count) 
from (select count(c3.challenge_id) as count from challenges c3 group by c3.hacker_id))) big
and  t.total1 = 1
)
      

group by h.hacker_id, h.name
order by total desc
```